# Qt QSortFilterProxyModel with custom TreeModel

Tags: qt, sorting, tree, treeview, qtreeview

i impemented this Editable TreeModel from Qt: [Editable TreeModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html)

All works fine as expected, then i have modified it for my special needs, and there i'm not storing Strings, i am storing X509 certificates and some general data of it like issuer and subject. So my treeview sturcture look like this:

```
Subject, Issuer, Valid Till, Certificate Data
```

Note that the Certificate Data is not shown in the tree view, only the three other fields. This works and so my tree view could look like this, if there are certificates which are signed by another certificate:

```
- Certificate A
    - Certificate B (which was signed by A)
    - Certificate C (which wassigned by B)
- Certificate D
- Certificate E
```

So i implemented a double click listener which returns the certificate data (field 4), which works fine.

Now i want to make the tree view sortable. Therefore i want to use QSortFilterProxyModel. Is this the right way? Or is there another / better solution?

So i tried the following and set up my model and the QSortFilterProxyModel this way:

```
QVector<X509*> certificates getCertificates(storeName);
m_model = new TreeModel(certificates);
m_proxy = new QSortFilterProxyModel;
m_proxy->setSourceModel(m_model);
ui->treeView->setModel(m_proxy);
ui->treeView->expandAll();
```

And then inside the double click listener im calling this:

```
QVariant data = m_proxy->data(m_proxy->index(index.row(), 4));
```

This works not correct, because when i click on Certificate B or Certificate C i got everytime the data of the Certificate which is stored under Certificate A. But i need to get the data which is stored under the correct entry (row). Where is my problem?

Comment: You will have to reimplement your own `QSortFilterProxyModel` and to override the `lessThen` function

Comment: sort did work, i only get the wrong data when i select a item in my treeview. I think `lessThen`is needed for sorting?

Comment: In that case, you need to pass the parent index (tree structure) `QVariant data = m_proxy->data(m_proxy->index(index.row(), 4, index.parent()));`

Comment: Thnaks, now it works as i want. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems to me your doubleclick listener is doing something weird. It should normally already have the model index of the item being clicked, and hence, also have access to any associated data. There should be no need to manually go through the proxies like you seem to be doing. You can just call .data() on the index you have already.

Comment: @André and what should be wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Simons comment the solution for the problem is to pass the parent index (tree structure), so that my code looks this:

```
 QVariant data = m_proxy->data(m_proxy->index(index.row(), 4, index.parent()));
```